# How can I get the customer increment ID in an observer in Magento2 if using the human friendly ID

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer

I am trying to get a magento customer increment ID. I'm thinking I have to use the resource-model class just not sure what the best way to access it is or how to get it.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer $resourceModel,
){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->customerRepo = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    $this->customerResource = $resourceModel;
}

protected function execute(
    InputInterface $input,
    OutputInterface $output
)
{
    $email = 'email@email.com'
    $data =  $this->customerRepo->get($email);
    $cid =  $data->getId(); //checking exists
    $rsrd= $this->customerResource->loadByEmail($data,  $email);
    $incrementid =  $data->getAttribute('increment_id');
    $output->writeln( 'email: ' . $email . ' customer id: ' . $incrementid );
}
```

Comment: increment_id for customer doens't exist. Why do you need it ? Do you mean for customer's order instead ?

Comment: I'm developing a custom extension that links up a legacy ERP to magento via xml orders. Magento has to output a unique customer increment ID that is linked to an email address for every transaction, also I have to keep track and set custom customer account ID's  for customers. A10001 B100001 C100001 I'm getting magento to create and display the increment ID in the admin grids, but not sure how to get at it programitically when a new account is created.

Comment: Ok so I was just using the wrong class, just use  \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer,
`$magentoCustomer = $this->Customer->loadByEmail($email)->getIncrementId();`